# how can I remove all characters after the second occurrence of a ' ' (space)

Tags: python, regex, python-3.7

My name regex has been proven faulty on a couple entries:

```
find_name = re.search(r'^[^\d]*', clean_content)
```

The above would output something like this on a few entries:

```
TERRI BROWSING APT A # current output
```

So, I need a way to trim that out; it's tripping the rest of my program. **The only identifier I can think of is if I can somehow detect the second space; and remove all characters after it.**

I only need the first and last name; *i.e.*

```
TERRI BROWSING # desired
```

After I remove those characters I could just `.strip()` out the trailing space, just need a way to remove all after second space.... *or maybe detect only to get two words, nothing more.*

Comment: Maybe you need to also validate the first two words that must be uppercase ASCII letters? `re.match("[A-Z]+\s+[A-Z]+", s)`? Otherwise, `\S` based regex does not seem necessary, you may as well use `split`.

Answer (score 8):

You don't even need regex since you can use simple splits and joins:

```
text = 'TERRI BROWSING APT A'
' '.join(text.split(' ')[0:2])
```

```
# 'TERRI BROWSING'
```

Comment: I'm getting 'AttributeError: 're.Match' object has no attribute 'join'' with that.

Comment: This seems like you still try to use `re`.  Try `find_name = ' '.join(text.split(' ')[0:2])`

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
^\S+\s+\S+
```

- `^` matches the start of the string
- `\S+` matches one or more non-whitespaces
- `\s+` matches one or more whitespaces

---

Also, assuming the whitespace is actually a space character, you can find the index of the second space using **`str.find`** and slice the string upto that point:

```
text[:text.find(' ', text.find(' ') + 1)]
```

---

**Example:**

```
In [326]: text = 'TERRI BROWSING APT A'                                                                                                                                                                     

In [327]: re.search(r'^\S+\s+\S+', text).group()                                                                                                                                                            
Out[327]: 'TERRI BROWSING'

In [338]: text[:text.find(' ', text.find(' ') + 1)]                                                                                                                                                         
Out[338]: 'TERRI BROWSING'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove the rest, you could match 2 times a non whitespace char `\S*` followed by a space and capture that in a group. Then match any char 0+ times and replace with the first capturing group using [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub)

```
^(\S* \S* ).*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Lx3NIn/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/ALn3jl)

```
import re

print(re.sub(r"^(\S* \S* ).*", r"\1", "TERRI BROWSING APT A"))
```

Result

> TERRI BROWSING