# Removing repeated trailing characters from a string in Python

Tags: python, regex, pandas, string

I have a field with comments. Some of the comments are just "no" but with varying trailing "o"s. I want to do a transformation to these comments, such that I only get "no" returned. How can I achieve this using regex?

Eg:

`remove_trailing_os("noooooo")` should output "no"

`remove_trailing_os("nooOOoooooooo")` should output "no"

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I don't think this is a duplicate. The linked question does not refer explicitly to regex, nor to trailing characters or case insensitive match

Comment: @mozway Sorry...I thought those uppercase Os were just typos.

Comment: "How can I achieve this using regex?" Well, what do you know about regex? Can you think of a regex pattern that matches the part you want to replace? Do you know what you want to replace it with? Do you know how to do the replacement? *What actually is the difficulty*?

Comment: Since you are creating a function `remove_trailing_os` you can get your result without using regex. Use `str.startswith`. eg: ` if input.startswith("no") return "no"` if the "no" is of different case in different inputs then use `re.search(r'^no', input_string, re.I)`. It will return a match object or return `None` .

Answer (score 3):

You could use a case insensitive backreference:

```
import re
re.sub(r'(.)(?i:\1)+$', r'\1', "nooOOoooooooo", re.I)
```

output: `'no'`

regex:

```
(.)        # match a character
(?i:\1)+$  # match trailing case insensitive repeats of the character
```

Answer (score -1):

This seems similar to [how can I remove all characters after the second occurrence of a ' ' (space)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57260974/how-can-i-remove-all-characters-after-the-second-occurrence-of-a-space)

but essentially you want to replace space with o. Hence

```
## Assuming the two instances
t = 'noooooo'
t2 = 'nooOOoooooooo'
## Trying them on the two instances
t[:t.find('o',t.find('o')+1)]
t2[:t2.find('o',t2.find('o')+1)]
```